# Handling a csv file as a list of vectors of unequal length

Tags: r

I want to import a .csv file which contains lists (in columns) of numeric vectors of unequal length (the longest is 5000 characters, the shortest less than 200). I then want to run the function `Shannon()` from the package QSutils on each one of these imported columns/vectors. This function returns the entropy of the vector.

To import the data, I'm using the following code:

`df = read.csv('C:/Filepath/File.csv', header = TRUE)`.

The resulting data frame has NA values inserted into many of the columns, because the column lengths are all different. So when I then use the `Shannon()` function:

`entropy <- Shannon(df[[column1]]`

I get a correct result if the column has a length of 5000, but a message indicating (I think) the presence of NA values in the vectors:

`The input object must be a numeric vector`

How can I import my data in a way which does not insert NA values? Alternatively, how can I transform it efficiently?

The structure of the dataframe (output of `dput(head(df))` is below:

```
structure(list(ï..irrigate_all = c(712L, 667L, 501L, 452L, 323L, 
306L), thrive_all = c(6689L, 5315L, 3555L, 3045L, 2713L, 2454L
), deduct_all = c(5492L, 5181L, 4414L, 4182L, 3325L, 2463L), 
    migrate_all = c(3359L, 1515L, 1443L, 1272L, 1260L, 1254L), 
    nourish_all = c(6206L, 4865L, 2836L, 1261L, 812L, 746L), 
    purr_all = c(934L, 241L, 113L, 102L, 70L, 57L), glow_all = c(2706L, 
    2231L, 2077L, 861L, 814L, 613L), abduct_all = c(1119L, 974L, 
    444L, 434L, 308L, 282L), oscillate_all = c(293L, 191L, 180L, 
    160L, 147L, 108L), roar_all = c(1525L, 1374L, 806L, 597L, 
    425L, 378L), eject_all = c(1234L, 977L, 664L, 595L, 425L, 
    420L), dawdle_all = c(78L, 27L, 22L, 18L, 16L, 11L), whack_all = c(688L, 
    253L, 165L, 155L, 152L, 131L), afford_all = c(15201L, 5555L, 
    4319L, 4128L, 4112L, 3580L), attach_all = c(10977L, 7646L, 
    7626L, 6689L, 5708L, 5130L), dwindle_all = c(1624L, 699L, 
    530L, 238L, 188L, 174L), limp_all = c(200L, 156L, 151L, 148L, 
    135L, 127L), fall_all = c(26061L, 21304L, 19129L, 18288L, 
    17023L, 15596L), sprinkle_all = c(10732L, 6396L, 5606L, 4765L, 
    3316L, 2702L), extinguish_all = c(4715L, 1855L, 724L, 619L, 
    513L, 426L), relieve_all = c(28693L, 15142L, 14474L, 11246L, 
    5043L, 3789L), meditate_all = c(1896L, 934L, 654L, 538L, 
    363L, 313L), surge_all = c(1727L, 1478L, 1004L, 867L, 861L, 
    845L), grumble_all = c(409L, 378L, 153L, 143L, 104L, 98L), 
    triumph_all = c(261L, 245L, 228L, 202L, 202L, 188L), flinch_all = c(93L, 
    70L, 65L, 64L, 52L, 48L), hibernate_all = c(370L, 333L, 282L, 
    211L, 142L, 137L), injure_all = c(5222L, 4502L, 4333L, 3337L, 
    2611L, 2466L), bicker_all = c(146L, 145L, 107L, 102L, 95L, 
    84L), exist_all = c(14554L, 12132L, 11876L, 11557L, 8864L, 
    8261L), avoid_all = c(33514L, 21165L, 18014L, 17274L, 15795L, 
    14778L), acquire_all = c(15201L, 5554L, 4319L, 4127L, 4112L, 
    3580L), terrify_all = c(886L, 717L, 428L, 385L, 375L, 342L
    ), defy_all = c(3547L, 3297L, 3024L, 2642L, 2589L, 1440L), 
    swoop_all = c(465L, 428L, 390L, 186L, 177L, 160L), vanquish_all = c(364L, 
    258L, 161L, 96L, 65L, 56L), waddle_all = c(277L, 185L, 34L, 
    32L, 32L, 30L), propel_all = c(1335L, 959L, 946L, 876L, 769L, 
    663L), inquire_all = c(959L, 782L, 765L, 737L, 636L, 622L
    ), expire_all = c(9919L, 7696L, 7016L, 6363L, 6093L, 5755L
    ), swoon_all = c(348L, 277L, 158L, 144L, 130L, 87L), raise_all = c(96932L, 
    93142L, 68091L, 65720L, 46555L, 42759L), illuminate_all = c(3204L, 
    2430L, 1642L, 1106L, 1018L, 957L), carry_all = c(25088L, 
    23186L, 18291L, 17858L, 15161L, 14560L), bark_all = c(10167L, 
    679L, 473L, 422L, 298L, 269L), appear_all = c(27700L, 23628L, 
    21571L, 19379L, 17806L, 16542L), eliminate_all = c(50374L, 
    12491L, 10386L, 7013L, 5924L, 5329L), seethe_all = c(57L, 
    45L, 42L, 41L, 40L, 37L), hesitate_all = c(3767L, 922L, 767L, 
    700L, 663L, 547L), enhance_all = c(43406L, 20152L, 19253L, 
    16910L, 16670L, 16579L), recede_all = c(2473L, 785L, 538L, 
    507L, 403L, 398L), devour_all = c(1245L, 549L, 439L, 399L, 
    394L, 364L), dilute_all = c(7712L, 4092L, 2706L, 2143L, 1120L, 
    984L), depart_all = c(6682L, 3579L, 3422L, 3202L, 2954L, 
    2838L), lick_all = c(3974L, 2553L, 1770L, 1465L, 910L, 880L
    ), glisten_all = c(494L, 190L, 150L, 142L, 130L, 129L), underline_all = c(2434L, 
    1237L, 1186L, 1104L, 825L, 813L), rise_all = c(37464L, 24101L, 
    17350L, 16679L, 16040L, 11206L), grovel_all = c(43L, 39L, 
    33L, 30L, 29L, 14L), occur_all = c(52954L, 42672L, 39027L, 
    38235L, 25575L, 22700L), emerge_all = c(5735L, 4119L, 3989L, 
    3725L, 3245L, 3136L), mope_all = c(88L, 48L, 21L, 17L, 15L, 
    14L), expedite_all = c(5736L, 786L, 668L, 653L, 573L, 504L
    ), stitch_all = c(2056L, 1975L, 1965L, 1511L, 1424L, 1265L
    ), furnish_all = c(3493L, 1808L, 1657L, 1568L, 1334L, 1243L
    ), sparkle_all = c(905L, 341L, 282L, 231L, 208L, 201L), dissect_all = c(296L, 
    239L, 218L, 195L, 185L, 179L), snooze_all = c(162L, 149L, 
    93L, 79L, 77L, 76L), flow_all = c(29052L, 15366L, 15234L, 
    12185L, 9596L, 8313L), scold_all = c(275L, 157L, 148L, 97L, 
    96L, 79L), rescue_all = c(5237L, 4594L, 4030L, 3765L, 2938L, 
    2766L), baffle_all = c(503L, 251L, 217L, 139L, 139L, 134L
    ), shiver_all = c(385L, 179L, 169L, 128L, 124L, 115L), happen_all = c(243904L, 
    40280L, 39096L, 28251L, 20099L, 16313L), pollinate_all = c(1042L, 
    822L, 599L, 455L, 305L, 252L), subside_all = c(3174L, 2148L, 
    596L, 514L, 473L, 433L), gratify_all = c(671L, 210L, 178L, 
    169L, 156L, 126L), pacify_all = c(95L, 70L, 69L, 62L, 56L, 
    54L), crush_all = c(1773L, 1381L, 1138L, 1132L, 912L, 870L
    ), detect_all = c(8161L, 6100L, 5847L, 5321L, 4486L, 3758L
    ), tremble_all = c(1615L, 1503L, 963L, 754L, 753L, 509L), 
    strangle_all = c(1821L, 315L, 225L, 207L, 200L, 176L), stow_all = c(491L, 
    399L, 389L, 349L, 307L, 298L), promote_all = c(32122L, 28792L, 
    23546L, 20130L, 19387L, 13633L), bury_all = c(7506L, 4115L, 
    3715L, 3010L, 2987L, 2675L), erupt_all = c(4093L, 1990L, 
    1759L, 1314L, 1086L, 1039L), fidget_all = c(232L, 219L, 130L, 
    119L, 105L, 101L), trounce_all = c(101L, 71L, 69L, 54L, 40L, 
    38L), knead_all = c(5183L, 1463L, 1320L, 933L, 541L, 330L
    ), retrieve_all = c(13333L, 10973L, 4023L, 3381L, 2940L, 
    2232L), inject_all = c(4285L, 1666L, 1637L, 1447L, 1361L, 
    1337L), ache_all = c(2517L, 1397L, 1378L, 946L, 802L, 756L
    ), kneel_all = c(787L, 384L, 381L, 349L, 340L, 326L), wince_all = c(82L, 
    77L, 76L, 58L, 48L, 46L), expel_all = c(1754L, 1335L, 862L, 
    848L, 767L, 692L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There are no list columns in the data that you have shared.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what this means. Do you mean that changing the format of my data to list columns could help to solve the problem?